# Change quality of built-in recording script

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I've recently bought ScreenFlow, but I noticed that the recording quality is horrible, and even worse when uploaded to Youtube.

After some research I have to the conclusion that it records using Mac OSX Mountain Lion's screen capturing script that most programs use to record the screen.

So my question is, how do I change the quality at which this script records? I don't mind hacking stuff.

If this is not possible, what would be a good stand-alone program that can record by it's own account, not depending on this screen capturing script.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using your Mac's built-in microphone? That's more likely to be the source of quality issues than the codecs involved. Test by recording a track in Garageband, and see if that quality is what you expect.

Comment: I am using my headset's mic, but the problem is not the audio, it's the video. It's like it records at half the amount of pixels, at low quality (like watching fullscreen at 360p).

Comment: Sorry, my brain seems to have inserted audio before "recording quality".

Comment: No problem. :) So I guess you don't have a working answer then correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded a trial version of [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm), and it looks like there are a few ways to improve the video quality.

### YouTube Export

If you're using the YouTube publishing option, be sure to check the **Publish in 720p/1080p** option:
[image: YouTube quality options]

If you don't have that selected, the video will be downscaled by YouTube to 360p. You may also want to check the **Letterbox** option to maintain the aspect ratio on YouTube.

### Custom Export

You can gain more control over the export options by using the **Export** option, in the *File* menu (or ⌘E). There are various presets, I would suggest trying the *Web - High* option first, and see if that's to your taste. You'll also want to be sure to change the **Dimensions** settings, which by default are set to scale to 50%.

If you're wanting to put stuff on YouTube, I suggest exporting at your default resolution (*i.e.* 100% scaling) — YouTube will re-encode it anyway, but uploading the best source material is the best way to maintain quality. If you find the quality of the *Web - High* isn't sufficient, you can click the **Customize…** button, and increase the *Datarate* setting.

### Lossless Export w/ 3rd Party Tools

Finally, if you're still not satisfied, you could ScreenFlow's lossless recording, and use an external tool to compress it. To enable lossless recording, open **Preferences**, click *Advanced* and change the *Screen Recording Compression* from *Adaptive* to **Lossless**. Then when you export, use the *Lossless* preset (or *Lossless - ProRes*, although this format is not supported by as many tools). Then use another tool, such as [Handbrake](http://www.handbrake.fr/) to tweak the settings as you desire.

Hopefully you can find something amongst these options that will get you the output you desire.

Comment: EXCELLENT!! Sorry for all caps, but I've been searching for this for 2 days. It was the Lossless settings which made it low quality at recording. I will be sure to check out Handbrake. Thanks a lot! I can't believe Lossless was the option, well, I guess you should always try everything.